# Ocultar um tabela após o clique

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho uma tabela que lista os clientes de uma empresa. O usuário seleciona o cliente que deseja através dos links em cada .
Ao clicar os dados da tabela alimentam os inputs do formulário. Só que agora eu desejo esconder a tabela, visto que o usuário já selecionou o registro que gostaria.

A tabela eu listo assim:

```
<table class="table" id="tabelaCliente">

        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <i>
                    Cliente
                </i>
            </th>
            <th>
                <i>
                    Telefone
                </i>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        foreach ($query as $linha) {
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td id="<?php echo $linha->id ?>"> <a href=""><?php echo $linha->nome ?></a></td>
                <td><?php echo $linha->telefone . ' ou ' . $linha->celular ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Para alimentar os inputs do form eu uso AJAX:

```
$(document).on("click","#tabelaCliente td a",function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    var id_cliente = $(this).parent().attr("id");

    $('#nome').val($(this).text());
   // para ocultar eu faço
    $('#tabelaCliente').hide('slow');
    // já tentei isso também
   // document.getElementById('tabelaCliente').style.display = "block";

});
```

Meu problema está em ocultar a table, não vai... Alguém sabe como fazer?

Comment: Tente $("#tabelaCliente").css("display", "none"); e para exibi-la novamente caso precise $("#tabelaCliente").css("display", "block"); Ou seja none esconde e block exibe.

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo

Comment: Tranquilo Rafa, sorte ai !

Answer (score 0):

Acho que [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15698646/4551469) é bem o que você precisa:

```
$('#tabelaCliente td a').click(function() {
    //o que precisar fazer..

    $('#tabelaCliente').toggle('slow');
});
```

Comment: Melhor editar e colocar o seu código dentro de um $( document ).ready(function() {} para não haver erros caso o dom não tenha sido completamente carregado!

Comment: Obrigado @rLinhares, mas ainda não oculta.

Comment: @RafaelSalomão realemente deve ficar dentro do `ready`, mas a ideia era deixar na resposta só a function mesmo, não o código inteiro.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/m15h14k7/, Peguei o code do linhares que funciona, e montei o exemplo. Olha lá funcionando. Tá fazendo algo errado!

Comment: Tranquilo @rlinhares!

Comment: @RafaelChristófano acho que o problema é essa estrutura (`tabelaCliente td a`) que não deve estar correta; vê o html gerado se seria esse caminho mesmo.

Comment: Sim, a estrutura é essa: tenho a table id="tabelaCliente, em seguida segue o cabeçaho da tabela, logo em seguida faço um laço exibindo os dados em uma <tr><td>, o conteudo das celulas <td> possuem um ink <a>

Comment: o comentário acima do @RafaelSalomao, logo após minha pergunta deu certo. Não tinha visto antes. Obrigado a todos